# Omiting setResultsName in pyparsing expression

Tags: python, dictionary, pyparsing

Pyparsing documentation shows how to use *setResultsName(...)* method to set a resulting dictionary key. However, I saw a few times that this method is omitted and just *(...)* is used.
What I mean is:

Instead of:

```
exp1 = pp.Word(pp.alphas).setResultsName('word1')
exp1.parseString( "Hello" ).asDict()
```

... one can do:

```
exp1 = pp.Word(pp.alphas)('word1')
exp1.parseString( "Hello" ).asDict()
```

... and the result is going to be exactly the same.

So 2 questions:

1. Where can I find the document confirming that omitting *setResultsName* can be done?
2. How does that work? Is *pp.Word(pp.alphas)*, being a pyparsing object, a function? How is it implemented then?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the pyparsing documentation [online](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/).

The documentation for [setResultsName](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#setResultsName) says:

> Define name for referencing matching tokens as a nested attribute of
>   the returned parse results. NOTE: this returns a *copy* of the
>   original ParserElement object; this is so that the client can define a
>   basic element, such as an integer, and reference it in multiple places
>   with different names.
>
> You can also set results names using the abbreviated syntax,
>   expr("name") in place of expr.setResultsName("name") - see `__call__`.

The information for [`__call__`](https://pythonhosted.org/pyparsing/pyparsing.pyparsing.ParserElement-class.html#__call__) confirms this behavior.

Since the ParserElement class implements `__call__`, that makes instances of that class callable, like a function. In this case, calling a ParserElement instance with a string argument is equivalent to calling `setResultsName`.